Specifying Service Account in Custom Job
we are using a python code to start some custom training jobs, my problem is that even using a service account "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com" to start the job, the job uses inside it a ""service-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-compute@gcp-sa-aiplataform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com" account, what is breaking my code because this second don't has all bigquery permissions, is it possible to run de job using the "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com"? I tried it in several ways but none of them worked.
def create_custom_job(
        project: str,
        display_name: str,
        container_image_uri: str,
        args: list,
        machine: str="n1-standard-4",
        location: str = "northamerica-northeast1",
        api_endpoint: str = "northamerica-northeast1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
):
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    client = aiplatform.gapic.JobServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    custom_job = {
        "display_name": display_name,
        "job_spec": {
            "worker_pool_specs": [
                {
                    "machine_spec": {
                        "machine_type": machine,
                    },
                    "replica_count": 1,
                    "container_spec": {
                        "image_uri": container_image_uri,
                        "command": [],
                        "args": args,
                    },
                }
            ]

        },
    }
    parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"
    response = client.create_custom_job(parent=parent, custom_job=custom_job)
    return response
temp=create_custom_job(
            display_name="yyyyyyyyyyyyya",
            container_image_uri="container_image_path",
            args=["--a=c"],
            project='project_name',
            machine='n1-highmem-16'
        )


did you resolve the issue?
I have the same issue, i m trying to run a custom job in vertex ai with a specific service account
i did it with the Gcloud command but not with python

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
